# Vuejs Update child component's data when parent updates prop sent to child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent component. It sends data in a prop to a child. That child also needs to update the value, so I followed this [pattern](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow):

> The prop is used to pass in an initial value; the child component wants to use it as a local data property afterwards. In this case, it’s best to define a local data property that uses the prop as its initial value.

You can see example code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-gmh5n. You can see it running here: https://gmh5n.csb.app/.

**Problem**

When I update the parent's data value, it updates the prop sent to the child (I can see that in Vue.js devtools). But the child's local data value is not updated.

**Question**

Is it possible to update the child's local data value when the prop sent by the parent is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to watch if `initialCounter` is changed from parent.

```
export default {
  name: "ChildWithProps",
  props: ["initialCounter"],
  data: function() {
    return {
      counter: this.initialCounter
    };
  },
  watch: {
    initialCounter(newInit) {
      this.counter = newInit;
    },
  }
};
```

Then If you want to update parent initialCounter in child, you need to pass function as prop to child.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it, https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-b2d8w

Instead of creating a data in child make it emit an event and update data in parent when event happens